# How to sort this array according to month and date?

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this array according to its month

```
["Month", "Apple", "Banana", "Mango"]
1: (4) ["Apr-08", 30, 0, 0]
2: (4) ["Apr-16", 26, 0, 21]
3: (4) ["Jul-08", 16.25, 9.25, 0]
4: (4) ["Feb-07", 58, 0, 0]
5: (4) ["Feb-08", 11, 0, 0]
6: (4) ["Jun-07", 4, 0, 0]
7: (4) ["Jul-07", 2.25, 0, 0]
```

I am expecting this result after sorting according to its month and date ?

```
["Month", "Apple", "Banana", "Mango"]
1: (4) ["Feb-07", 58, 0, 0]
2: (4) ["Feb-08", 11, 0, 0]
3: (4) ["Apr-08", 30, 0, 0]
4: (4) ["Apr-16", 26, 0, 21]
5: (4) ["Jun-07", 4, 0, 0]
6: (4) ["Jul-08", 16.25, 9.25, 0]
7: (4) ["Jul-07", 2.25, 0, 0]
```

I think i should create variable which belong all months like this and compare

```
var allMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Convert date to timestamp, then compare timestamps in `sort` callback function

Comment: can you use a regular date format instead of "Jan-01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```js
const ary = [
  ["Apr-08", 30, 0, 0],
  ["Apr-16", 26, 0, 21],
  ["Jul-08", 16.25, 9.25, 0],
  ["Feb-07", 58, 0, 0],
  ["Feb-08", 11, 0, 0],
  ["Jun-07", 4, 0, 0],
  ["Jul-07", 2.25, 0, 0]
]

const output = ary.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[0]) > new Date(b[0]) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ary = [
  ["Apr-08", 30, 0, 0],
  ["Apr-16", 26, 0, 21],
  ["Jul-08", 16.25, 9.25, 0],
  ["Feb-07", 58, 0, 0],
  ["Feb-08", 11, 0, 0],
  ["Jun-07", 4, 0, 0],
  ["Jul-07", 2.25, 0, 0]
]

const output = ary.sort((a, b) =>
  new Date(a[0]) > new Date(b[0]) ? 1 : -1
)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
 ["Apr-08", 30, 0, 0],                  
 ["Apr-16", 26, 0, 21],
 ["Jul-08", 16.25, 9.25, 0],
 ["Feb-07", 58, 0, 0],
 ["Feb-08", 11, 0, 0],
 ["Jun-07", 4, 0, 0],
 ["Jul-07", 2.25, 0, 0]];

 var allMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return allMonths.findIndex((e) => e === a[0].substr(0, 3)) -  allMonths.findIndex((e) => e === b[0].substr(0, 3))
 }    
 );
```